# Converting long[64] to byte[512] in Java?

Tags: java, porting

I'm porting a process over to Java. There's already working versions in C# and C++.

I have a section in C# that I do Marshal.Copy(...) to convert 64 ulongs to 512 bytes and that line in C++ I use memmove(...) to do the same thing. What is available in Java to achieve the same result? I need the same binary information in the same order just as bytes instead of longs.

Edit:

The reason I'm porting to Java is to take advantage of the portability that Java naturally has. I would not like to use native code.

Another thing. Since Java doesn't contain unsigned values, then I need to change what I'm requesting by just a little. I would like to attain the 8 unsigned byte values from each of the 64 longs (ulongs in C# and C++) so that I can use those values at indices in arrays later. This needs to happen thousands of times so the fastest way would be the best way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) works well for this: just put in 64 `long` values and get a `byte[]` out using the `array()` method. The [`ByteOrder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html) class can handle endian issues effectively. For example, incorporating the approach suggested in a comment by [wierob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136264/wierob):

```
private static byte[] xform(long[] la, ByteOrder order) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(la.length * 8);
    bb.order(order);
    bb.asLongBuffer().put(la);
    return bb.array();
}
```

Addendum: The resulting `byte[]` components are signed, 8-bit values, but Java arrays require [nonnegative integer index values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html). Casting a `byte` to an `int` will result in sign extension, but masking the higher order bits will give the unsigned value of `byte b`:

```
int i = (int) b & 0xFF;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137690/java-operator-precedence-guidelines) elaborates on the applicable operator precedence rules. This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201422) demonstrates a similar approach for `double` values.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion is easier to read and potentially more efficient. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#views