# Java: Convert byte to integer

Tags: java

I need to convert 2 byte array ( byte[2] ) to integer value in java.  How can I do that?

Comment: This question could use some clarification. As it stands now, we will only see what you mean by which answer you select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read two bytes into an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768933/read-two-bytes-into-an-integer)

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(myArray);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);  // if you want little-endian
int result = buffer.getShort();
```

See also [Convert 4 bytes to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2383265/139010).

Comment: Thank you this worked.  Will ByteBuffer takes care of signed and unsigned bytes?

Comment: @keshav: what do you mean? There is no such thing as a "signed" or "unsigned" byte. A byte is just a group of `0` s and  `1` s; the **only** meaning is in how you interpret those numbers.

Comment: @Matt:  Once the conversion is done, if the converted number is negative ( say -100 ), will I see it as -100?

Comment: @keshav: why don't you try it and see? :) Honestly - I don't know without testing it myself.

Comment: @keshav: I tested it. `ByteBuffer` will handle this correctly. That is, **iff** the bytes represent a negative number, then this code will output a negative `int`. Demos: [here](http://ideone.com/MUe5p) and [here](http://ideone.com/xwBIW). Remember, it's only negative if the most significant (leftmost) bit is `1`.

Comment: This won't work, as `+` has higher precedence than `<<`, so `a << 8 + b` is the same as `a << (8 + b)` which is not at all what you want.  In addition, `byte` in java is signed, so bad things will happen if the low-order byte is negative.

Comment: This answer should be split, because the first part is wrong, while the ByteBuffer part is nice and clean, and actually works.

Comment: @MattBall yep, upvoted! I actually got bitten by the wrong part, although I wrote it myself :)

Answer (score 11):

In Java, Bytes are signed, which means a byte's value can be negative, and when that happens, @MattBall's original solution won't work.

For example, if the binary form of the bytes array are like this:

> 1000 1101  1000 1101

then myArray[0] is `1000 1101` and myArray[1] is `1000 1101`, the decimal value of byte `1000 1101` is `-115` instead of 141(= 2^7 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0)

if we use

`int result = (myArray[0] << 8) + myArray[1]`

the value would be `-16191` which is WRONG.

The reason why its wrong is that when we interpret a 2-byte array into integer, all the bytes are
unsigned, so when translating, we should map the signed bytes to unsigned integer:

`((myArray[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (myArray[1] & 0xff)`

the result is `36237`, use a calculator or ByteBuffer to check if its correct(I have done it, and yes, it's correct).

Answer (score 3):

Well, each byte is an integer in the range -128..127, so you need a way to map a pair of integers to a single integer.  There are many ways of doing that, depending on what you have encoded in the pair of bytes.  The most common will be storing a 16-bit signed integer as a pair of bytes.  Converting that back to an integer depends on whether you store it big-endian form:

```
(byte_array[0]<<8) + (byte_array[1] & 0xff)
```

or little endian:

```
(byte_array[1]<<8) + (byte_array[0] & 0xff)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you can use the Guava library:

```
Ints.fromByteArray(0, 0, myArray[1], myArray[0]);
```

It was worth mentioning since a lot of projects use it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this:

```
return new BigInteger(byte[] yourByteArray).intValue();
```

Works great on Bluetooth command conversions etc. No need to worry about signed vs. unsigned conversion.

Comment: Note there's a constructor in this class where you can manually specify you wish to handle unsigned values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
public class ByteArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f=new File("c:/users/sample.txt");
        byte[]b={1,2,3,4,5};
        ByteArrayInputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        int i;
        while((i=is.read())!=-1) {
            System.out.println((int)i); 
            FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream(f);
            FileOutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream b1=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b1.write(6545);
            b1.writeTo(f1);
            b1.writeTo(f2);
            b1.close();
        }
```