# Read two bytes into an integer?

Tags: java, integer, byte, arrays

I have a `byte[]` that I've read from a file, and I want to get an `int` from two bytes in it. Here's an example:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x2F, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x6F};
int value = bytes.getInt(2,4); //This method doesn't exist
```

This should make `value` equal to `0x0110`, or `272` in decimal. But obviously, `byte[].getInt()` doesn't exist. How can I accomplish this task?

The above array is just an example. Actual values are unknown to me.

Comment: the reason the answers work is that the bytes are promoted to integers in case that's what was causing you trouble understanding.  "bytes[2] * 256" doesn't fit in a byte, but it's not an issue because "256" is an integer, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert 4 bytes to int ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383265/convert-4-bytes-to-int)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should just opt for the simple:

```
int val = ((bytes[2] & 0xff) << 8) | (bytes[3] & 0xff);
```

You could even write your own helper function `getBytesAsWord (byte[] bytes, int start)` to give you the functionality if you didn't want the calculations peppering your code but I think that would probably be overkill.

Comment: Ideally it should be (b1 << 8) | (b2 & 0x00ff)
If second byte value is greater than 128, the above conversion gives incorrect value, as java considers the byte as negative int.

Comment: Why the `0xff`? In other words, what's the difference to `bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]`?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
public static int getInt(byte[] arr, int off) {
  return arr[off]<<8 &0xFF00 | arr[off+1]&0xFF;
} // end of getInt
```

Your question didn't indicate what the two args (2,4) meant.  2 and 4 don't make sense in your example as indices in the array to find ox01 and 0x10,  I guessed you wanted to take two consecutive element, a common thing to do, so I used off and off+1 in my method.

You can't extend the byte[] class in java, so you can't have a method bytes.getInt, so I made a static method that uses the byte[] as the first arg.

The 'trick' to the method is that you bytes are 8 bit *signed* integers and values over 0x80 are negative and would be sign extended (ie 0xFFFFFF80 when used as an int).  That is why the '&0xFF' masking is needed.  the '<<8' shifts the more significant byte 8 bits left.
The '|' combines the two values -- just as '+' would.  The order of the operators is important because << has highest precedence, followed by & followed by | -- thus no parentheses are needed.

Comment: Thx for this nice explanation. For the same thing but signed value, I used: `return arr[off]<<8 | arr[off+1]&0xFF;`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice simple reliable way.

```
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
    // by choosing big endian, high order bytes must be put
    // to the buffer before low order bytes
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    // since ints are 4 bytes (32 bit), you need to put all 4, so put 0
    // for the high order bytes
    byteBuffer.put((byte)0x00);
    byteBuffer.put((byte)0x00);
    byteBuffer.put((byte)0x01);
    byteBuffer.put((byte)0x10);
    byteBuffer.flip();
    int result = byteBuffer.getInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
int val = (bytes[2] << 8) + bytes[3]
```

Comment: No: it will return a negative int if bytes[2] is bigger than 0x7f. The "& 0xff" from paxdiablo's answer is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ByteBuffer. It has the getInt method you are searching for and many other useful methods

Answer (score 0):

The Google Base16 class is from Guava-14.0.1.

```
new BigInteger(com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base16().encode(bytesParam),16).longValue();
```