# How do I take the byte value out of this class?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to take the byte value out of this class so I can parse it, or if it's possible parse it inside and get the 5th and 6th byte value out.

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
    // carried out as per profile specifications:
    // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();




        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());




        } else {
            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.


        }

    }


    sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

How this works is that I step on a scale and it sends me these bytes:

```
00 00 00 00 02 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Which is stored at the variable 'data'. How do I take 'data' out to use in another class?

The weight data is on bytes 5 and 6. If you convert the hex values of bytes 5 and 6, in that example is '`0202`' it becomes 514 in decimal (51.4kg).

I need to take the bytes data to use in another class to get the kg data. How would I go around doing so?

Comment: `data[5]*256+data[6]` ? If you want to convert it to float (kg) value `double weight = (data[5]*256+data[6])/10.0` ?

Comment: Yup, I got that down. However, I need to get the byte data(which is stored in the variable 'data') out of the class to use it. I'm guessing through intents or something, I'm not too sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get those two bytes and apply below:

```
int result = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```

If you want more info: [HERE1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383265/convert-4-bytes-to-int), [HERE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492711/java-convert-byte-to-integer)

Comment: Would I be able to access 'result' through another class?

Comment: Ah OK. there was an another question. I see intent which seems like you are using Android. in that case are you talking about another activity instead of another class?

Comment: Oh, that one is separate. I want to get the value of result for example to another class. Like to call result to be able to take the value and manipulate it. Thanks mate.

Comment: OK. you can either apply above implementation where you receive it and if the rest of data are not needed then, you can only extract this and send.

Comment: Ah, how do you send? That's the part I'm a bit confused about. I can't access the data on my other class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137477/passing-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-another-activity

Comment: I not very sure but I believe you omit to specify the class name of the intent.