# AmazFit Bip Watch - Heart Rate

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to show Heart Rate value for the `AmazFit Bip Watch` in my own application.
**UUID:**

```
00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

**Sample Byte Array:**

```
byte[0] = 0
byte[1] = 70
```

**Calculated value from the byte array:**

```
if (value.length == 2 && value[0] == 0) {
    final int hrValue = (value[1] & 0xff);
}
```

**Question:** I am not getting correct value whatever I see in the watch. I want exact value in my application what I see in the watch. I have referred [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) project.

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the following code:

```
Byte b = byte[1];
final int hrValue = b.intValue();
```

or use Byte constructor as below:

```
Byte b = new Byte(byte[1]);
final int hrValue = b.intValue();
```

Thanks to [byte to int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581563/639293)