# Incorrect colors on Android Bitmap after conversion to and from a byte array

Tags: android, arrays, colors, bitmap, argb

In Android, I want to load a PNG, get the RGB values in a byte array to do some computation, then I want to recreate a Bitmap with the new values.
To do that, I wrote 2 functions to convert a Bitmap into an RGB byte array and another one to convert an RGB byte array back to a Bitmap, the alpha channel can be ignored.

These are the conversion functions:

```
public static byte[] ARGB2byte(Bitmap img)
{
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = new int[height*width];
    byte rgbIm[] = new byte[height*width*3];

    img.getPixels(pixels,0,width,0,0,width,height);

    int pixel_count = 0;
    int count=width*height;

    while(pixel_count < count){
        int inVal = pixels[pixel_count];

        //Get the pixel channel values from int
        int a = (inVal >> 24) & 0xff;
        int r = (inVal >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g = (inVal >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b = inVal & 0xff;

        rgbIm[pixel_count*3] = (byte)(r);
        rgbIm[pixel_count*3 + 1] = (byte)(g);
        rgbIm[pixel_count*3 + 2] = (byte)(b);

        pixel_count++;
    }

    return rgbIm;
}

public static Bitmap byte2ARGB(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{

    int pixelsCount = data.length / 3;
    int[] pixels = new int[pixelsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelsCount; i++)
    {
        int offset = 3 * i;
        int r = data[offset];
        int g = data[offset + 1];
        int b = data[offset + 2];
        pixels[i] = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

So I tried to test these function just loading an image from the asset folder, converting it to byte array, converting it back to Bitmp immediately and saving it to the internal storage to inspect if the final result matches the original image.
Unfortunately it doesn't, the color space seems wrong.

For example if I load this png:
[image: original]

and run the following code:

```
// Loads the png from assets folder
AssetManager am = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open(filename);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

// Conversion to byte array
byte[] barray = ARGB2byte(bitmap);
Bitmap reconverted = Utils.byte2ARGB(barray, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

// Saving the reconverted Bitmap
try {
        String folder_path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        File file = new File(folder_path + "test_conversion.png");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        reconverted.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("saving bitmap", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("saving bitmap", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

I get this as result:

[image: reconverted]

What I'm doing wrong?
If I use the same code to save the original Bitmap right after I loaded it, the image I get is correct, so I'm probably doing some mistake during the conversion.

I also inspected the R,G,B values of the byte array of the original image comparing them with th values from the byte array obtained from the reconverted image, and they are the same!!
Is there something that the Bitmap library of Android does under the hood, maybe with the alpha channel? I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for I can't speak English well first.

It's cause cast byte to int in java will get unexpected result.

Use this instead

```
int r = data[offset] & 0xFF;
int g = data[offset + 1] & 0xFF;
int b = data[offset + 2] & 0xFF;
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581530/converting-from-byte-to-int-in-java) too.