# How to convert int to byte in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, int, byte

I have this integer in java:

```
int i = 1067030938;
byte b = (byte) i;
```

which gives me:

```
-102
```

> How could I go from `b` back to `i` ?

---

I tried :

```
b = b & 0xff;
```

but this gives `154`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from byte to int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581530/converting-from-byte-to-int-in-java)

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 hey thanks for the link, I checked it before :) If you see I am using `b & 0xff` (solution suggested there as well) but for some reason it doesnt work.
Also I am using java 11 and for some reasone `int i = Byte.intValue();` doesnt come as an option. Let me know tho, if you think I am using something wrong! Piece

Comment: The int value (1067030938) is far outside the range (-128 to 127) of the byte type.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i don't really understand what you're trying to archieve with this. casting `(int) b` returns `-102`. What output do you expect?

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 hey as stated in my question I try to from byte back to int. That means I want to go from `-102` to `1067030938`

Comment: @hispanicprogrammer You were already told several times that this is not possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
int i = 1067030938;
```

And just want the low order 8 bits, then do

```
i &= 0xff;

System.out.println(i);
```

Prints

```
154
```

If you want the signed value of converted int then do this

```
i = (byte)i; // will be -102
```

Comment: what would be the proper way to go from byte back to the integer value  `1067030938` ?

Comment: You can't.  A byte is only 8 bits.  It's maximum value is 127.  The other bits are lost in the conversion.