# ==operator comparison of int and byte

Tags: java, compare, operator-keyword

//code start

```
int a=3;
byte b=3;
if(a==b)  --> returns true
```

//code ends

- Query :

  IT returns true because compares the bits in a and b.
  a = 00000011
  b = 00000011

  here only bit pattern comparison is done and zeros left at the end in int  doesn't matter.

  what does the above line conveys??

Comment: [It](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581563/6332074) might help.

Answer (score 2):

In java automatic type conversion converts any small data type to the larger of the two types. So `byte b` is converted to `int b` when you are comparing it with `int a`.

Do know that `double` is the *largest* data type while `byte` is the *smallest*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than only comparing the least significant 8 bits of the two operands like you guessed, the compiler adds 24 0s or (or 1s if the byte is negative) to the byte to make it the same size as the int. This is known as *binary numeric promotion* and is specified in [§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) of the JLS. The conversion from `byte` to `int` is specified in [§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).