# Cannot convert from to - Java's implicit type conversion and an unary operator

Tags: java

```
byte b1 = 3 + 5;
```

The literals `3`, `5` and `3 + 5` are of type `int`.
The expression above works because Java internally converts the result of `3 + 5` from `int` to `byte`, or?

The same explanation should work in the case of `b2`:

```
    byte b1 = 3 + 5;
    byte b2 = b1 + 5; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
```

But it does not.

Why?

Comment: The difference: `3` and `5` are compile time constants, so `3 + 5` can be evaluated at compile time and the whole line is simplified to `byte b1 = 8;`. But `b1` is not a compile time constant, so this does not work with the line `byte b2 = b1 + 5;`.

Comment: Watch this conversation, maybe it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581530/converting-from-byte-to-int-in-java

Comment: The second conversation works if you declare b1 `final`. The compiler simply considers the possibility that the non final variable might have changed by the second line and therefor be to big to fit in another byte

Comment: The operands of `+` undergo binary numeric promotion: in the second case, it is effectively `(int) b1 + 5`, the result of which is a non-compile-time constant `int`. In the first case, both operands are compile-time constants (and ints), so the result is a compile-time constant int; the compiler can check that result is within the range of `byte`, and so can implicitly narrow the result.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of `+` undergo binary numeric promotion: that is, they are widened where necessary to make them compatible for addition. The rule is quite simple:

- If either operand is a double, widen the other to double
- If either operand is a float, widen the other to float
- If either operand is a long, widen the other to long
- Otherwise, widen them both to int

in the second case, it is effectively `(int) b1 + 5`, the result of which is a non-compile-time constant `int`. This can't be guaranteed to be in the range of `byte`, so the compiler complains.

In the first case, both operands are compile-time constant ints, so the result is a compile-time constant int; the compiler can check that result is within the range of `byte`, and so can implicitly narrow the result.

Answer (score 0):

`int`s are implicitly cast to `byte`s in your previous assignments, to mimic the effect in the last statement you need to do it explicitly after java promotes b1 + 5 to an int, like this:

```
byte b2 = (byte) b1 + 5;
```

alternatively if you declare `b1` as `final`, the compiler will check the ranges and do the assignment (with an implicit cast) as you expected originally, since `3 + 5`it is in the range of `byte`s and b1 will not be changing its value (`3`):

```
final byte b1 = 3;
byte b2 = b1 + 5;
```