# Packing data to byte[]

Tags: java, python, arrays, marshalling

I need something similar to Python's struct module for a Java project. I would like to pack integer (and perhaps floats and doubles as well) into byte arrays. Furthermore, I want to choose the endianness and generally have full control over how this is done because I need to send this data to some hardware which will be running code in another language.

Comment: Maybe something like: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html?

Comment: Maybe you can just use Python? Probably not, though. SO sorry.

Comment: Exactly like that Walkerneo. Want to put that in an answer and maybe flesh it out a bit for anybody reading this question so I can check it off as the accepted answer?

Comment: @BigEndian, I'll put it as an answer. Lemme play with it a bit first before the fleshing-out though :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: [Convert 4 bytes to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383265/convert-4-bytes-to-int), you can use [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

Answer (score 3):

For an int var you can take each byte of the int and put on the array. Like that:

```
int info = 123456789;
byte [] data = new byte[100];
data[0] = (byte) ((info>>24) & 0xff);
data[1] = (byte) ((info>>16) & 0xff);
data[2] = (byte) ((info>>8)  & 0xff);
data[3] = (byte) ((info)     & 0xff);
int out = 0;
out = ((data[0]&0xff)<<24) | ((data[1]&0xff)<<16) | ((data[2]&0xff)<<8) | data[3]&0xff);
System.out.println("info " + info);
System.out.println("out  " + out);
```

For a float or double you can't do like that directly. It's necessary convert your var to an int. It can be done using the methods [Float.floatToRawIntBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29) or [Double.doubleToRawLongBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) .

Comment: Better use [`floatToRawIntBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29) or [`doubleToRawLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) instead of fooling around with "multiplying by an constant like 1000000"...

Comment: @glglgl thanks, using floatToRawIntBits() is really better. I will upgrade my answer.