# swap big endian java then to decimal

Tags: java, decimal, hex, endianness

Little confused on the whole big endian, little endian thing even after reading up on it. Say I have a Hex value of...

```
AA 37 D6 08 DF BF CB 01
```

and I want to convert it to...

```
01 CB BF DF 08 D6 37 AA
```

(Which is big endian right?) How would I do this in Java? Once thats done I would need to convert it to decimal. Sorry if this is straight forward I'm quite new to this as my head is spinning from it lol. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What does it mean to convert it to decimal?

Comment: To convert the hex to decimal, 1CBBFDF08D637AA is 129407978957060010 is deciaml.

Comment: A value is a value is a value regardless of hex vs. decimal and big vs. little endian -- until you **store** it, **transmit** it, or **access** it one byte at a time.  So, what is the *source* of your original hex value `AA 37 D6 08 DF BF CB 01`?  Are you reading it from a file or network stream?  Is it binary data coming as bytes in that order, or is it a character stream of hex digits?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this will sometimes print extra 00s on the end that you may need to trim in the hexSwap.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Simon {

    public static String hexSwap(String origHex) {
        // make a number from the hex
        BigInteger orig = new BigInteger(origHex,16);
        // get the bytes to swap
        byte[] origBytes = orig.toByteArray();
        int i = 0;
        while(origBytes[i] == 0) i++;
        // swap the bytes
        byte[] swapBytes = new byte[origBytes.length];
        for(/**/; i < origBytes.length; i++) {
            swapBytes[i] = origBytes[origBytes.length - i - 1];
        }
        BigInteger swap = new BigInteger(swapBytes);
        return swap.toString(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String orig = "AA37D608DFBFCB01";
        String swap = hexSwap(orig);
        System.out.println(swap);
    }

}
```

Comment: this method is nice but will throw a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the input string is 00000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

For reference, just looking at a bunch of bytes won't tell you whether a number is little-endian or big-endian ( unless you happen to already know the number they represent).  The reason you have to care in the first place, is that the same bytes represent two different numbers depending on whether the bytes should be interpreted as little-endian or big-endian.

Now that that's said, if you know the bytes represent a little-endian number, and you want to interpret it as a Java `long`, you could use some code like:

```
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    result |= (bytes[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
}
```

Once you have that, you can use `Long.toString(result, 16)` to show the result as a hex number if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined below, you can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to interpret a value as either a big- or little-endian quantity. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212025). As a convenience, note that the  `double` constructor of `BigDecimal` "Translates a double into a `BigDecimal` which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value."

Console:

```
400921fb54442d18 = 3.141592653589793
182d4454fb210940 = 3.207375630676366E-192
3.141592653589793 = 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

Code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200863 */
public class DoubleOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pi = Math.PI;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Double.SIZE / 8);
        bb.putDouble(pi);
        display(bb, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        display(bb, ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        System.out.println(pi + " = " + new BigDecimal(pi));
    }

    private static void display(ByteBuffer bb, ByteOrder order) {
        bb.order(order);
        Long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(bb.getDouble(0));
        String s = Long.toHexString(bits);
        Double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.valueOf(s, 16));
        System.out.println(s + " = " + d.toString());
    }
}
```