# Assigning a value to a variable in a chain in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Order of Operations - Using Two Assignment Operators in a Single Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440844/java-order-of-operations-using-two-assignment-operators-in-a-single-line)

If we assign a variable a value in a chain like the following,

```
int x=10, y=15;
int z=x=y;

System.out.println(x+" : "+y+" : "+z);
```

then the value of all three variables `x`, `y` and `z` becomes `15`.

---

I however don't understand the following phenomenon with an array.

```
int array[]={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int i = 4;

array[i] = i = 0;    
System.out.println(array[0]+" : "+array[1]+" : "+array[2]+" : "+array[3]+" : "+array[4]);
```

It outputs `10 : 20 : 30 : 40 : 0`. It replaces the value of the last element which is `array[4]` with `0`.

Regarding previous assignment statement - `int z=x=y;`, I expect the value of the first element means `array[0]` to be replaced with `0`. Why is it not the case? It's simple but I can't figure it out. Could you please explain?

---

By the way, this assignment statement `array[i] = i = 0;` is dummy and it has no value of its own in this code and should no longer be used but I just wanted to know how thing actually works in this case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440844/java-order-of-operations-using-two-assignment-operators-in-a-single-line

Comment: I think `array[i]` is evaluated as `array[4]` at the compile time itself (May be some optimization done by Compiler).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int i = 4;` when i equals to 4 the `array[i]` equals to `array[4]` so `array[i] = i = 0;` is equivalent to `array[4] = i = 0;`. That is way it change the value of index 4 with 0.

Comment: This is the first one as well as correct one. Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 7):

**The separators [] and () change precedence. Everything within these separators will be computed before Java looks outside them.**

```
array[i] = i = 0;
```

During compiler phases, the first change to this line will happen as follows:

```
array[4] = i = 0; // subscript separator is evaluated first.
```

Now, assignment operation is right-associative, So, `i` is assigned value `0` and then array[4] is assigned value of `i` i.e. `0`.

Check following links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12

Answer (score 3):

Let me break it....

**Your statement:**

`int array[]={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};`

**Implementation:**

```
array[0] => 10

array[1] => 20

array[2] => 30

array[3] => 40

array[4] => 50
```

**Your statement:**

`int i = 4;`

**Implementation:**

```
i => 4
```

**Your statement:**

`array[i] = i = 0;`

**Implementation:**

```
array[4] = i = 0;

array[4] = 0
```

Well if you want `array[0] => 0`, then do this...

```
int i = 0;

array[i] = i = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

because `array[i]` is evaluated before assignment opeartion