# Using ` LinkedBlockingQueue` may cause null pointer exception

Tags: java, null, final, linkedblockingqueue

I am learning java concurrent programming recently. I know that the `final` keyword can guarantee a safe publication. However, when I read the `LinkedBlockingQueue` source code, I found that the `head` and `last` field did not use the `final` keyword.  I found that the `enqueue` method is called in the `put` method, and the `enqueue` method directly assigns the value to `last.next`. At this time, `last` may be a `null` because `last` is not declared with `final`. Is my understanding correct? Although `lock` can guarantee `last` read and write thread safety, but can `lock`  guarantee that `last` is a correct initial value instead of `null`

```java
public class LinkedBlockingQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E>
        implements BlockingQueue<E>, java.io.Serializable {
transient Node<E> head;
private transient Node<E> last;
public LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        last = head = new Node<E>(null);
    }
 private void enqueue(Node<E> node) {
        // assert putLock.isHeldByCurrentThread();
        // assert last.next == null;
        last = last.next = node;
    }

public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
        if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        // Note: convention in all put/take/etc is to preset local var
        // holding count negative to indicate failure unless set.
        int c = -1;
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e);
        final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        putLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            /*
             * Note that count is used in wait guard even though it is
             * not protected by lock. This works because count can
             * only decrease at this point (all other puts are shut
             * out by lock), and we (or some other waiting put) are
             * signalled if it ever changes from capacity. Similarly
             * for all other uses of count in other wait guards.
             */
            while (count.get() == capacity) {
                notFull.await();
            }
            enqueue(node);
            c = count.getAndIncrement();
            if (c + 1 < capacity)
                notFull.signal();
        } finally {
            putLock.unlock();
        }
        if (c == 0)
            signalNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: They can't be `final` because they get changed. Make  a variable `final` doesn't guarantee it is never null. Your question does't tmake sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this blog post https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/ even writing to one `final` property in constructor is enough to achieve safe initialization (and thus your object will be always published safely). And `capacity` property is declared as `final`.

> > In short, we emit a trailing barrier in three cases:
> >
> > A final field was written. Notice we do not care about what field was actually written, we unconditionally emit the barrier before exiting the (initializer) method. That means if you have at least one final field write, the final fields semantics extend to every other field written in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `last` is equal to a `node` with a `null` value. However this is intentional. The `lock` is only meant to ensure that each thread can perform modifications in this class correctly.

Sometimes using `null` values is intentional, to indicate a lack of value (empty queue in this case). Because the variable is `private` it can only be modified from within the class, so as long as the one writing the class is aware of the possibility of `null`, everything is alright.

I think you are confusing multiple different concepts which are not necessarily connected. Note that because `last` is `private` there is no publication. In addition `head` and `last` are meant to be modified, so they can't be `final`.

#### Edit

Perhaps I misunderstood your question...

`null` is never assigned to `last` directly. So the only place this could happen is in the constructor, before `last` is assigned `new Node<E>(null)`. Although we can be sure that the constructor finishes before it is used by many threads, there is no visibility guarantee for the values.

However `put` uses a `lock` which does guarantees visibility in use. So if there was no `lock` used, then `last` could actually be `null`.

Comment: I meant  that last may be null (last == null)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss understanding about the  of Java's [continuous assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440844/java-order-of-operations-using-two-assignment-operators-in-a-single-line)

```java
//first last is inited in the constructor
last = head = new Node<E>(null); // only the filed's value in last is null(item & next)

// enqueue
last = last.next = node;
//equals:
last.next = node;
last = last.next;
```

Only if you call `last.next` otherwise there will no NPE.

Comment: I meant that last may be null (last == null)

Comment: I understand, but last is inited in the constructor method. `last = head = new Node<E>(null);` so last will not be null, only the fields inside is null