# Can someone explain how recursion works in these procedures

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

This is using MIT Scheme, coming from the infamous SICP. I just can't wrap my head around what is happening.
Here's a procedure to compute `N!`.

```
(define (factorial n)
     (if (= n 0)
          1
          (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

Here's a procedure to compute Fibonacci

```
(define (fib n)
   (cond ((= n 0) 0)
         ((= n 1) 1)
   (else (+ (fib (- n 1))
            (fib (- n 2))))))
```

Comment: Have you seen recursion in other languages? It might help to know if your question about recursion in Scheme or about recursion in general.

Comment: No, I have not seen recursion in languages. I'm asking for recursion in scheme only.

Comment: The Fibonacci recursion is discussed in some detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920001/recursion-two-calls-in-one-statement   The example is in C but that really doesn't matter.

Comment: In factorial function uses (if(= 0 1) and it should be (if(=0 n) . current version always return 1.

Answer (score 2):

In the SICP book there's a clear, step-by-step explanation of how [linear recursion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1) works (for the factorial example), and there's also a good explanation complete with a nice tree diagram detailing [tree recursion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2) (for the fibonacci example).

If you need an easier-to-understand explanation of how recursion works in general in a Scheme program, I'd recommend you take a look at either [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) or [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), both books will teach you how to grok recursive processes in general.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion takes some time to understand, so be patient with yourself.

I'd suggest imagining that you were the computer, and stepping through how you would compute `(factorial 4)`. Allow yourself to "be inside" a function multiple times at the same time by thinking of `(factorial 4)` and `(factorial 3)` (etc.) as completely different entities.