# Math parsing issues with double precision Java variables

Tags: java, parsing, math

I've got some heavy math to translate, from the apps I originally developed in VB6 to Java, and am running into a few issues with even the most basic equations.

For instance, why does this work,

```
double QD1=0;
QD1=24+c; QD1=QD1/513;
```

but this not work

```
double QD1=0;
QD1=(24+c)/513;
```

Also, I'm getting some non-linearity out of an equation that is completely linear, using doubles.  My system is 64-bit Fedora on a laptop built around 2006 or so. Is this likely to be a processor issue or a coding issue? Would I be better off using C++, or some kind of parser plug in?

Comment: For a math-heavy application where you have the choice of programming language, take a lool into [Julia](http://julialang.org). Having written quite a lot of mathematical code for web applications in the past, Java would not be my choice today.

Comment: Wow - just skimmed that description - very cool. :D

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
double QD1=0;
QD1=(double)(24+c)/513;
```

You need to cast integer `(24+c)` to double type.

Read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.2).

Comment: thank you - will I need to do this before every segment that is delimited by parentheses?  Like (double)(x/y)+(double)(z/y)

Comment: Another way is to do: `QD1=(24d+c)/513;` If you divide integer (`x`, `y`, `z` in your case) you should cast it to double. If `x`, `y`, `z` have double type you should not add extra casting.

Comment: Or you could just write your number literals as 24.0 and 513.0 so they are doubles, if that was your intent.... :)

Comment: @PaulAdamson Whenever you divide two integers, you get integer division (which throws away any remainder).  If `x` and `y` are integers, then `(double)(x/y)` does integer division on `x` and `y` *first*, because of the second set of `()`.  Then it converts the resulting integer to a `double`.  But this still throws away the remainder.  If you want a fractional result, you need `((double)x/y)` or something.  This converts `x` to a `double` before the division, so you will *not* get integer division.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete explanation for problems like this, see the answer to: [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This time, a direct answer:

> ...why does this work,

```
double QD1=0;
QD1=24+c; QD1=QD1/513;
```

`QD1` is clearly a `double`. To Java, 24 is an integer constant. If `c` is an integer type, `c` is added to 24 using integer arithmetic and the result is converted to `double` and then assigned to `QD1`. If `c` is a floating point type, 24 is promoted to `double`, added to `c` and the `double` result is assigned to `QD1`. Either way, the division of `QD1` is a double divided by an integer constant. The integer constant is promoted to double and floating point division is performed with a double result assigned to `QD1`.

> but this doesn't.

```
double QD1=0;
QD1=(24+c)/513;
```

In this case, if `c` is an integer type, the entire expression on the right-hand side operates on integers and returns an integer type. In Java, integer division truncates any fractional part which might result if the division were instead performed using floating point values and operators. Once evaluation of the right-hand side has completed, the integer result is promoted to `double` before assigning it to `QD1`, but by then, the fractional part of the intended result has already been lost.

The way to prevent this particular problem in practice is to always provide a fractional part to all integer constants used in floating point calculations. E.g. Change the code in both examples to use `24.0` and `513.0` for the constants. Always do this even in code which works as expected. Future edits may "break" the implementation when integer types are not intended.

Comment: Thanks for giving a thorough answer.  I really appreciate your time. :)