# Unexpected output for multiple assignment with arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Consider

```
int b = 2;

int[] a = new int[4];

a[a[b]] = a[b] = b = 2;

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

The output is

```
2
0
2
0
```

I was expecting `a[0]` to be zero.

Comment: Why would you ever have such code? Any statement with three assignments in is a bad idea...

Comment: @Pshemo: Great spot and the accepted answer on the duplicate is excellent.

Comment: @Bathsheba All credits to TheEnd. He found it and posted link in his answer. I just flagged it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from JLS 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =

> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.13),
>   possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand
>   array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes
>   abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>   same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array
>   access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and no
>   assignment occurs.

This means that `a[a[b]]` evaluates to `a[0]` as it's evaluated first. Then we proceed simply as `a[0] = a[b] = b = 2`, with the assignment taking place from right to left.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1

Answer (score 1):

Because `a[a[b]]` is same as `a[0]` and you are assigning value 2 for that..

```
b = 2, a[b] = 0 so a[a[b]] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[a[b]] = a[b]=b=2` , This executes from left hand side

First

```
a[a[b]] i.e, a[a[2]] -> a[0] //initially the value of a[2] will be 0
```

now,

```
a[0]=a[2]=b=2;
```

so the output is,

```
2 0 2 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this thread might help you to understand the evaluation order in java:
[What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

The most important part of this problem is that the first `=` is the actual assignment. In java the index is always evaluated befor the asignment, therefor `a[a[b]]` is the fist one in the evaluation order. And at this point `a[b]` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what `a[a[b]] = a[b]=b=2;` does in detail:

`a[a[b]]` : b is 2, `a[2]` is 0, `a[a[2]]` is `a[0]`.

so `a[a[b]] = a[b]=b=2;` is evaluated to `a[0] = a[b]=b=2;`

that is evaluated to `a[0] = a[2] =2;`, so `a[2]` is 2 and `a[0]` is equal to `a[2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading

a[a[b]] = a[b]=b=2;

from right to left and expecting the array and b to be reevaluated at each step, when in fact it seems like a and b are frozen at the time of the assignment. Consider the equivalent code:

```
1) int b = 2;          

//array initialized to 0
2) int[] a= new int[4]; // 0 0 0 0   

// at this point a[b] is a[2] = 0, therefore  below a[a[b]]=2 is equivalent to  a[0]=2
3) a[a[b]] = 2          // 2 0 0 0    

// the same: a[b] = 2 is equivalent to a[2] = 2  -note that the arrays are zero based
4) a[b]= 2              // 2 0 2 0

5) b=2;
```