# java short circuit operators

Tags: java, operators

My doubt is about the precedence of short circuit operators.

Classic example of short circuit operator is below.

if(denom != 0 && num/denom > 10 )

Here usage of shorthand operator allows us to prevent division by zero error because num/denom is never executed.

Now My question is Java says '/' operator has higher precedence than '&&' , then how come left side of '&&' is evaluated before '/'.?

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with associativity.

Comment: Because they are interpreted as two discrete evaluations and not one long one.

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with order of evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/` has higher precedence than `>`, which has a higher precedence than `&&`. So, the expression

```
a && b / c > 0
```

is the same as

```
a && (b / c) > 0
```

which is the same as

```
a && ((b / c) > 0)
```

The expression is then evaluated from left to right.

If `a` is false, then the entire expression is false, without even evaluating the second term.

If `a` is true, then `b / c` is first evaluated, and the result is compared to 0.

Comment: +1 precedence determines where the implied parenthesis are, not the order of evaluation (though it is rated).

Comment: Thank you guys, I got confused with precedence and associativity and order of evaluation of subexpressions. After reading your comments I got the idea where I was going bonkers. Also delving more into the topic I found another stack overflow answer that explains it all in depth. Posting the link so that others may find it usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java. Again thank you all for helping me