# In Java, which gets executed first, "+" or "++"?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I tried the following code in Java

```
t1 = 5;
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
System.out.println (t2);
```

My view is since ++ has a higher precedence than +, the above becomes

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
t2 = t1 + 6;      // t1 becomes 6 here
t2 = 6 + 6;
t2 = 12;
```

However, I get the answer 11 for t2. Can someone explain?

Comment: Try to avoid `++/--` in compound expressions. While this behavior is well-defined in Java, it produces different results (ie. 12) in perl and results in undefined-behavior in C/C++. Plus, it often makes the expression harder to quickly analyze.. (case in point, perhaps)

Comment: The fact that this is considered "undefined behavior" in C should give you a heads up that it's probably not a good idea to use the construct in any language. It seems to me there is just too much opportunity for not getting the answer you would expect. Do everyone a favor and use two lines of code - your future self will thank you...

Comment: I think it's a good question, but rather interesting than useful: you should just avoid increment/decrement operators in compound expressions (see comments above) and save yourself a headache.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You are nearly correct but you are subtly misunderstanding how the precedence rules work.

Compare these two cases:

```
int t1 = 5;
int t2 = t1 + (++t1);
System.out.println (t2);

t1 = 5;
t2 = (++t1) + t1;
System.out.println (t2);
```

The result is:

```
11
12
```

The precedence does indeed say to evaluate the `++` before the `+`, but that doesn't apply until it reaches that part of the expression.

Your expression is of the form `X + Y`
Where `X` is `t1` and `Y` is `(++t1)`

The left branch, i.e. `X`, is evaluated first.
Afterwards the right branch, i.e. `Y`, is evaluated.
Only when it comes to evaluate `Y` the `++` operation is performed.

The precedence rules only say that the `++` is "inside" the `Y` expression, they don't say anything about the order of operations.

Comment: I love/hate that when you look at those two statements it appears you're turning `a = b + c` into `a = c + b` and yet they produce two different results.

Answer (score 55):

Your logic is close, but not quite right.  The order of evaluation is Left to Right for the + operator.  t1 comes before the binary op, LHS and then the increment is on the RHS of that binary op.  The LHS is executed first.

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
t2 = 5 + 6;      // t1 becomes 6 here as a side effect before being read on the RHS
t2 = 11;
```

Visualised as a tree you have,

```
    +
  /   \
 t1   ++t1
```

*Precedence Order*

When two operators share an operand the operator with the higher precedence goes first. For example, 1 + 2 * 3 is treated as 1 + (2 * 3), whereas 1 * 2 + 3 is treated as (1 * 2) + 3 since multiplication has a higher precedence than addition.

*Associativity*

When two operators with the same precedence the expression is evaluated according to its associativity. For example x = y = z = 17 is treated as x = (y = (z = 17)), leaving all three variables with the value 17, since the = operator has right-to-left associativity (and an assignment statement evaluates to the value on the right hand side). On the other hand, 72 / 2 / 3 is treated as (72 / 2) / 3 since the / operator has left-to-right associativity.

Comment: IMO "[the] logic is not so close". Vivek is confusing evaluation order and precedence in his question. The point should be made that they are quite different.

Answer (score 15):

Another way of thinking of it is to expand the ++ expression:

`++t1` is the same as putting `t1 = t1 + 1`.

```
1) t1 = 5;
2) t2 = t1 + (++t1); 
3) t2 = t1 + (t1 = t1 + 1), 
4) t2 = 5 + (t1 = t1 + 1)
5) t2 = 5 + (t1 = 6)
6) t2 = 5 + 6 = 11
```

If you were to reverse the order to `t2 = (++t1) + t1;` Then the expression would expand to:

```
1) t2 = (t1 = t1 + 1) + t1     
2) t2 = (t1 = 5 + 1) + t1
3) t2 = (t1 = 6) + t1
4) t2 = 6 + 6 = 12
```

Answer (score 5):

To add a point to Chris K,

**The associativity is from left to right**

So,

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
t2 = 5 + 6;      // first t1 is replaced with 5 and then the next 6 
t2 = 11;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `+` is evaluated from left to right, so

```
t1 + (++t1)     // Left side is evaluated to 5, right side evaluated to 6...
5  + (6)        // ...and as a side effect t1 becomes 6
```

Results in `11`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of t1 in the second line is 5

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1)
t2 = 5 + 6;      // t1 becomes 6 here
```

The [evaluation order is from left to right.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

So first t1 is evaluated to `5` then `++t1` to `6` and hence the result as `11`

Answer (score 2):

evaluation happen from left to right. So actually what happen is following

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
t2 = 5 + 6;      
t2 = 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

++x is executed before you use the variable x, and x++ increase x after you used it:

```
x=5;
y=x++;
y is 5;
and x is 6

x=5;
y=++x;
y is 6;
and x is 6
```

Comment: ++x and x++ are AFAIK executed at the same time, but they return an other value. ++x returns the new value, x++ returns the old value.

Answer (score 0):

```
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
```

This is equivalent to

```
temp = t1 + 1
t2 =  t1 + temp;
t1= temp;
```

Comment: Actually it's more like `temp = t1; t1++; t2 = temp + t1`

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
t1 = 5;
t2 = t1 + (++t1);
// it takes 5 for t1 and as it moves further to (++t1), it increments t1 to 6, so it takes 6 for  (++t1)
t2 = 5 + 6;
// (++t1) this increments t1 by 1 then return new value. So (++t1)=6
// (t1++) this returns old value n then increments t1 by 1. So (t1++)=5
```

Comment: Could you add a few lines to explain why you think your answer is best suited to answer the original question ? Thanks.