# Array assignment output behaves differently for two code snippets

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

First code snippet prints `2`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
    int val = (a = b)[3];
    System.out.println( a [val  ] );
}
```

Second code snippet outputs `1`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
    int val;
    System.out.println(a[val = ((a = b)[3])]);
}
```

What is going on?

[image: output1]

[image: 2nd output]

Comment: wow ! what a weird syntax. what were you trying to do ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev which java version you are using?I am attaching java screenshot..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Comment: @KumarAbhinav - I use jre 8. I can attach my code + output, but it wont be an answer. People might downvote.

Comment: I get 2 for first snippet and 1 for second in jre 7.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev attached the screenshots,I am too using java7 in eclipse

Comment: @KumarAbhinav - Looks like some serial downvoter is downvoting without even reading the answers. I just deleted the comment + code I posted in the answer section.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Wasn't the first line of your answer something like "This is not an answer..."

Comment: someone has tagged it as duplicate ,but rules for evaluation doesnt explain my doubt

Comment: @Takendarkk - yes. that is correct. But, I would never hold it against you if you told me that you downvoted me. Then...i'll serially downvote you...just kidding.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Why would you post an answer that starts with "This is not an answer"?

Comment: @Takendarkk - could not post it as a comment. That is why. Chenqui.

Comment: @Henry: I see that you marked this as a duplicate. However, I don't quite follow how this particular example is explained by Java's evaluation order rules. Would you mind spelling it out in an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @NPE see answer, the difference comes from the different evaluation order in the two snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is reasonable. Let's expand the two complicated lines into several separate statements. First snippet:

```
// This...
int val = (a = b)[3];
// Becomes...
a = b;
int val = a[3]; // 0
```

So printing `a[val]` will print `a[0]`, which is now 2.

The second snippet is more complicated. The tricksy bit is that "the array we're indexing into" is evaluated *before* the rest of the side-effects. So:

```
// This...
System.out.println(a[val = ((a = b)[3])]);
// Becomes...
int[] tmp = a; // So tmp is { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
a = b;
val = a[3]; // 0
System.out.println(tmp[val]); // 1
```

[JLS section 15.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.4) goes into more detail about this. The important parts here are:

> At run time, evaluation of an array access expression behaves as follows:
>
> - First, the array reference expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly [...] evaluated.
> - Otherwise, the index expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly [...]
> - Otherwise, if the value of the array reference expression is null [...]
> - Otherwise, the value of the array reference expression indeed refers to an array. If the value of the index expression is less than zero [...]
> - Otherwise, the result of the array access is the variable of type T, within the array, selected by the value of the index expression.

Comment: Someone mentioned that the output is different in JRE 8. I haven't verified this myself, but is there any reason to expect this to behave differently across Java versions (or implementations)?

Comment: @NPE I tested it with Java 8. No difference. And I doubt there is any.

Comment: @NPE: Nope - and it gives 1 for me under JRE 8. I suspect a diagnostic error on the part of the person reporting a value of 2.

Comment: @NPE Can output vary for a JLS specification across different compiler versions for a single vendor?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav: Not sure what you mean, but given that Borat appears to have removed his comment claiming that the second snippet produces 2 as well, my guess is that he hadn't recompiled, or something like that.

Comment: @NPE: If Borat's deleted answer is anything to go by, the problem was that he ran snippet 1 and then snippet 2... by which time `a` already referred to a different array. Definite red herring.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir,it's an awesome analysis for Borat's comment

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet the interesting part is

```
int val = (a = b)[3]
```

Here there are two assignments. The first one (`a = b`) will happen first and lets the variable `a` also reference the array that `b` refers to (note that the old array is not referenced anymore and thus is eligible to being garbage collected).

Afterwards you ask for the element on index 3. And that is the value "0". The output then asks for the element on index 0 in that array. And as you can see, this is the value "2". Remember that `a` now refers to the same array as `b`.

In the second code snippet you are doing all in the same line:

```
System.out.println(a[val = ((a = b)[3])]);
```

Although the assignments and indexing look the same, the major difference here is that you are accessing the array (referenced by `a`) *before* you reassign the variable.

So after all assignments are done, the variable `val` has the same value "0" and the variable `a` refers to the same array as `b`. But now the first element (index 0) in the old array will be looked up. And that is "1".

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of the Java Language specification (15.13.1. Run-Time Evaluation of Array Access) states:

> An array access expression is evaluated using the following procedure:
>   First, the array reference expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes
>   abruptly for the same reason and the index expression is not
>   evaluated.
>   Otherwise, the index expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes abruptly for the same reason.

The first snippet is the easy part: after the statement `int val = (a = b)[3];` the array variable `a` points to the array `{ 2, 3, 1, 0 }` taking the element at index 0 gives the answer 2.

In the second snippet the `a` is evaluated before the index expression, so `a` points to the array `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`. Taking the element at index 0 this time gives the answer 1.

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };

int val = (a = b)[3];
/**
* a=b => a = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
* val = a[3] = 0;
* a[val] => a[0] =>2;
**/

System.out.println( a [val  ] );  //2
```

second:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 1, 0 };
int val;
System.out.println(a[val = ((a = b)[3])]);
/**
* a[val = ((a = b)[3])]    
* => a[val=(b[3])]   val is not used here
* => a[b[3]] => a[0] => 1
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

there is two set of experssions:

**A:**

```
1. int val = (a = b)[3];
2. a [val]
```

and **B**:

```
1. a[val = ((a = b)[3])]
```

after executing **A.1**: `a={2,3,1,0}` and `val=0` so `a[val]=2`

when executing **B.1**: `a={1,2,3,4}` and `val=0` so `a[val]=1`

in **`B`** the `(a=b)` is a reference to `{2,3,1,0}` so `(a=b)[3]=0` and `val=0` and `a` is a reference to `{1,2,3,4}` (because the assignment does not complete yet) so `a[0]=1`

Comment: Someone mentioned that the output is different in JRE 8. I haven't verified this myself, but is there any reason to expect this to behave differently across Java versions (or implementations)?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "because the assignment doesn't complete yet". By the time the array is actually accessed, the assignment for `a = b` *has* completed... but the tricky bit is that it hadn't occurred when the evaluation determined which array was going to be accessed. There's a significant difference there.

Comment: @NPE I test it with java7 and java8 and the result is identical.

Comment: @طاهر the wordings of your answer may be misleading

Answer (score 0):

So in the first example, b is assigned to a, val equals the 4th value of b, 0, and then we print the value with index 0, 2. You got this.

In the second example, as all operations are done in one time, a still kept its initial value when accessing the index 0, so 1 is printed. The second snippet is equivalent to :

```
int val = b[3];
System.out.println(a[val]);
a =b;
```