# Assigning multiple values to an array in same statement

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

I have a java code snippet below:

```
int arr[] = new int[5];
int index = 0;
arr[index] = index = 3;

System.out.println("arr[0] = " + arr[0]);
System.out.println("arr[3] = " + arr[3]);
```

Output is:

```
arr[0] = 3
arr[3] = 0
```

What exactly is happening in line 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java language specification:

> **15.7** The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

In this case, `arr[index]` is evaluated first, producing a reference to element zero. This is because `index` is still `0`. Now `index = 3` gets evaluated, and `3` is stored in the index. Now the first assignment is ready to complete, so `3` is assigned to element zero.

Java language designers recommend to avoid relying on this rule for clarity, making sure that there is only one side effect to an expression. Your expression, however, has two side effects, one of which relies on the completion of the other.

> *It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions*.