# Why in java not allowed assignment and boolean operator without brackets

Tags: java, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, assign, boolean-expression

Sorry, for the strange  question formulation. If somebody has an idea how to make it better, I will be happy.
Lest imagine we have 3 boolean variable:

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = false;
boolean c = false;
```

Java allows to write the folowing:

```
System.out.println(a=b);
System.out.println(a==b & a==c);
```

And from this two statements I expected that the following is legal, too.

```
System.out.println(a=b & a=c);
```

My question is: why in the second case it isn't allowed, when it is allowed in the first one? In the second case both assignments resolved in boolean and & looks legal for me.

Comment: Ain't you missing `&&` --- an ampersand symbol! That's a bitwise and which has lower priority as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @shekharsuman Java _does_ have a `&` boolean operator; it is like `&&` except that it does not short circuit

Comment: @fge-That I mentioned in my comment too! You should check it,and,I wanted to say that it'll get short-circuited!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman sorry, reacted too fast; anyway, I believe the OP knows about this operator from the look of things

Comment: @fge one question touching this. I have not come across in my career where i need to use bitwise operator. Can you give some example where it may be required in practical scenario?

Comment: @MSach if you have to manipulate flags based on numeric values; for instance, [`Spliterator.characteristics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--). If you want to test, say, whether a spliterator has the `DISTINCT` characteristics, you'll test that `theSpliterator.characteristics() & DISTINCT == DISTINCT` (or `!= 0`). Granted, in Java you won't need it that much, but it is quite common in C. Another way is to get the next closest multiple of `n` where `n` is a power of 2: `nextMultiple = (orig + n - 1) & ~(n - 1);`

Comment: Thanx fge a lot. I will go in details of that and come back to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `=` has a lower priority than `&` (which, by the way, is a *boolean* operator in your snippets and not a bitwise operator; it is the same as `&&` except that it does not short circuit).

Therefore your expression reads (with parens):

```
a = (b & a) = c
```

But you can't assign `c` to `b & a`.

Comment: Thank you fge!!!! According to the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) you are absolutely right. And after more than one year of programming in Java, now I know operators precedence order))). And reading more [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java/6801431#6801431) got that Order of evaluation of subexpressions is independent of both associativity and precedence.

Comment: Well, anyway, the rule of thumb is always the same: if you don't remember about operator precedence, chances are that parens are "king", so use them when you are not sure ;)

Answer (score 9):

Change your last snippet to

```
System.out.println((a = b) & (a = c));
```

[The assignment operator (`=`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) has [lower precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than the [boolean logical AND operator (`&`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2). Use parentheses to explicitly group your expressions.

Comment: Hu? Is it not a bitwise and for boolean. (Yes there are only 1 bit, but you can still bitwise and them).