# operation on post++ and --pre operator

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

I am wondering with `post` and `pre` increment and decrement operation.

what I know in `Java` precedence of `post operator` is `high` and `associativity` is `left-to-right`.while associativity of `pre` operator is `right-to-left`

[image]

[Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

but my code showing me undesired result-

```
public class Bunnies { 
    static int count = 3; 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        System.out.println(--count*count++*count++);//out put is 12 expected 48
        //associativity of post is higher so should be evaluated like this-

        //--count*3**count++  count is 4 now
        //--count*3*4         count is 5 now
        //4*3*4=48


        count = 3;
        System.out.println(--count*++count*++count); //out put is 24 expected 120
        //associativity of pre  is right to left so should be evaluated like this-

        //--count*++count*4      count is 4 now
        //--count*5*4            count is 5 now
        //4*5*4=120


        count = 3;
        System.out.println(-- count*count++);// out put is 4 expected 9

        //--count*3      count is 4 now
        //3*3=9 
         }
}
```

Comment: I am checking how these `post` and `pre` works.not a part of real time appliaction.I am sound in `C` with these operator buy wondering me in java.

Comment: You should trust, and cite, the Java Language Specification over any other documentation  whatsoever, yea unto and including the Java Tutorial.

Comment: When you have --Number , then the number will decrease first then perform the next operation. And when you have Number++, then the the operation will be performed then the Number will be increased

Comment: The figure is for C++, not Java...

Comment: @ِAllloushI am following oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup this is done in java plz have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: I understand that, but why mix a C++ table into the question without a comment or tag?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7 and following oracle documentation of java,I used this image by googling but my result also varries if I follow only oracle documentation.@AndersR.Bystrup

Answer (score 3):

> **Order of evaluation of subexpressions is independent of both associativity and precedence.**

The subexpression of the multiplication are evaluated from left to right, so when doing `--count*count++*count++`, you evaluate `--count` then `count++` and finally `count++`.

And as the pre operator is evaluated first, `--count` will be decremented before its evaluation. In the same way, as the post operator is evaluated lately, `count++` will be incremented after its evaluation.

The precedence only help the compiler to create a correct abstract syntactic tree.
For example, when doing `++count*2`, the compiler use the precedence to know the expression is `(++count)*2` and not `++(count*2)`. In the same way, when doing `++count*count--`, the expression is `(++count)*(count--)` and not `(++(count * count))--` or whatever. But then, during the evaluation of the multiplication `++count` is evaluated before `count--`.

Hope this help you :)

I just found a great answer about expression evaluation in C# and Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801431/1498389), enjoy :)

Comment: role of multimlication come only after `pre`and `post` since they are higher in precedence,this is precedence all about not helpful in query.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians You misunderstand what is the precedence, and confuse it with the evaluation. When doing `++count*2`, the compiler create an AST (abstract syntactic tree) to evaluate the expression, and precedence is used to build this tree. Precedence of pre (or post) operator is higher, so it will be applied before the multiplication, but the multiplication is still evaluated from left to right. See my edit :)

Comment: yes @Nizil there is no matter either * evaluated r-l or l-t result will be same.but the values available for multiplication will evaluated on the basis of `post` and `pre` operator.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6801431/1498389) :)

Comment: this does not mean that we are using multiplication so rest values evaluated l-r.u can easily understand that bcz almost all the operator have l-r associativity so what does it mean pre operator has r-l associativity they always comes with any operator if u r using more than 1 in a single statement,then associativity of r-l will me meanning less pre operator,also this will become impossible to find a single example which can shoe r-l associativity of pre operator

Comment: the link you suggested is desired since associativity of `=`is right to left.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(--count*count++*count++);
```

= 2 * 2 * 3 = 12

```
count = 3;
System.out.println(--count*++count*++count)
```

= 2*3*4 = 24

```
count = 3;
System.out.println(-- count*count++);
```

= 2 * 2 = 4

**Pre increment/decrement**

`++/-- X` first increments/decrements then does the operation.

**Post increment/decrement**

`X ++/--` first the operation is done, then increment / decrement.

Comment: precedence of post is higher than pre what I mentioned in my question alrady. –

Comment: `post` operator will evaluated first.why U evaluated `pre` First.

Comment: The way U shown is fine to match with answer ,could please show the reason why u evaluated pre operator before post operator.

Answer (score 0):

I take the first one.

```
System.out.println(--count*count++*count++);//out put is 12 expected 48
                    2     *    2  * 3 = 12
                    pre   * post  * post
```

Comment: precedence of post is higher than pre what I mentioned in my question alrady.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians It does not matter, since you are using the `*` operator. It stands on his own.

Comment: K I have never seen logic that u suggested me now -this will not work due to presence of `*` strange!

Answer (score 0):

count = 3:

Example 1:

```
--count*count++*count++ equals (--count)*(count++)*(count++)
(--count) = 2
(count++) = 2 (you increment it AFTER you do something with it)
(count++) = 3 ... count was incremented from before
2*2*3 = 12
```

Example 2:

```
--count*++count*++count equals (--count)*(++count)*(++count)
--count = 2
++count = 3
2 * 3 * 3 = 24
```

Example 3:

```
(--count)*(count++)
--count = 2
2 * 2 (the count++ gets changed afterwards)
```

Keep in mind that you have to watch the multiplicaton operator

Comment: `post` operator will evaluated first.why U evaluated `pre` First.

Comment: I have added some brackets to show which is evaluated when.

Comment: role of bracket() is meaning less here since `post` operator and `()` have `same` `precedence`. both of these have highest precedence.

Comment: `--count*(count++)*(count++)`  is fine but you cant put pre operator in bracket by your own.putting in bracket`(--count)` changes my question.

Comment: The brackets are not a notation of programming but of grouping, in order to show which gets executed when. Dont look into your table for the brackets, use the brackets to see the order of evaluation. This is why I have written "equals" (see Nizils answer, he is pointing to the evaluation tree).