# java operator precedence DOT vs logical AND

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
if(fName != null && fName.isEmpty())
```

In this if expression we have 4 operators

```
1) . access object member
2) () invoke a method
3) != equality
4) && conditional AND
```

I have listed as per precedence and all have same associativity i.e left to right

Then why this expression evaluate in order below (to my knowledge)

```
1) !=
2) &&
3,4) . ()
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: I just want to know why compiler evaluates in a order against the precedency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Comment: it start to evaluate from () because of only that ur expression going to read by compiler.

Answer (score 3):

A logical AND operator (`&&`) is short circuited. It means the right operand is only evaluated if the left operand evaluates to true.

Therefore `fName != null` is evaluated first.

If it's true, `fName.isEmpty()` is evaluated next, and finally the `&&` operator itself is evaluated, since you can't evaluate it before you evaluate its operands.

Here are relevant quotes from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) :

15.7 :

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

15.7.1 :

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

15.7.2 :

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

Comment: .@Eran but && is having less precedence over . and () then why it evaluate first?

Comment: @AmitYadav The && operator has two operands - the left is `fName != null` and the right is `fName.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

- In Java, operands are evaluated left to right. So the !=, being part of the left operand of &&, and having higher priority, is evaluated first.
- The && operator doesn't evaluate its right operand if its left operand is false.

The operator *associativity* you posted has nothing to do with it.