# Why doesn't this if statement fail?

Tags: java, if-statement, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

Shouldn't this code produce a divide by zero exception?

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(6 > 5 || 5 / 0 == 0)
            System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

According to the [precedence rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqdvh.png) wouldn't the `5 / 0` get executed before the `6 > 5`, so I am under the impression that this code would fail due to a divide by zero exception.

I am aware that java short circuits if statements. So, if the first is true then it will evaluate to true, without even checking the second.

But, those precedence rules make it seem like the `5 / 0` would be executed first?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java

Comment: "According to the precedence rules wouldn't the 5 / 0 get executed before the 6 > 5" which precedence rule exactly makes you think so?

Comment: if statements evaluate left to right

Comment: No. In fact, your second test is *dead code* (because six is always greater than five). You could have verified this by swapping the order of the tests. Additionally, the single `|` would have worked as you expected in the sense that it doesn't *short circuit* (it still evaluates left-to-right). `if (6 > 5 | 5 / 0 == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't. The first side of the logical operator is evaluated in order for short circuiting. If statements evaluate left to right. In your example, the `6 > 5` is evaluated first because it's on the left of the logical operator. It's true so the next condition isn't checked. Now if you use the `|` operator, it will not short circuit:

```
if(6 > 5 | 5 / 0 == 0) { ... }
```

This will throw a `ArithmeticException` because both sides are evaluated.