# post-increment, pre-increment. JAVA

Tags: java, math, increment, post-increment

I understand the difference between this operations (post-increment, pre-increment).
But question: I have an expression:

```
int x = 4;
long y = x * 4 - x++;
```

The highest priority has post-unary operator, than "*" and last "-". In my opinion it will be:

```
long y = x * 4 - x++;

1). x++ => return 4 (save x = 5)
2). final expression: 5 * 4 - 4 = 16
```

But when I compile this in IDE the answer is `12` ! What's a problem and where did I do smth. wrong?

Comment: `x * 4` is evaluated first, which is 16. Then it evaluates `x++` which first gets `x` and then increases `x`. At the time of getting it is 4. so 16 - 4 = 12. If you were to change it to `++x`, then the answer would be 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are values in Java variables evaluated/returned/fetched in an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925647/when-are-values-in-java-variables-evaluated-returned-fetched-in-an-expression)

Comment: No, is not the same. Priority of "+" and "*" quite different

Comment: I don't understand WHY "*" is first?? [oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: expr++ has the hieghts priority!!
look at the example: int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x; the result will be 7 (if x = 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDITED***

Here are the steps to evaluate the expression:

1. Evaluate all the expression that has increment/decrement from left to right
2. Replace all variable with their true value
3. Evaluate the expression using [PEMDAS](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-pemdas-definition-rule-examples.html) rule

Example:

```
int x = 4;   
int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;
```

- first we need to substitute all values of `x` before evaluating the expression (substitute from left to right)
  `++x` -> since it is a post increment we will first increment `x` before substituting, thus `x` will be 5
  `5 * 5 / x-- + --x` -> this will be the new equation
  now we will substitute `x` in `x--`
  `x--` -> since it is a post decrement `x` here will be substituted with 5 and after the substitution decrement `x`, thus `x` will be 4
  `5 * 5 / 5 + --x` -> this will be the new equation
  now we will substitute `x` in `--x`
  `--x` -> since it is a pre decrement we will first decrement `x` substituting, thus `x` will be 3
  `5 * 5 / 5 + 3` // this will be the new equation
- Since there are no variables in the equation we will now evaluate the expression using PEMDAS
  `25 / 5 + 3` 
  `5 + 3`
  `8`
  thus the result will be 8

Comment: OK, but why this information in [of. oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) ?

Comment: It is basic math. It is not a Java only thing.

Comment: OK, basic maths. But why the result of long y =  - x++ + x * 4; is 13? By your words, the multiplication must be the first! But no, (x++) the first

Comment: And this:  int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x; result 7. It means, that all post/pre operators executed first

Comment: ```long y = -x++ + x * 4;``` will be 16. My explanation is incorrect. MDAS only applies to those without the increment/decrement. I have updated my explanation.

Comment: ```int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;``` will not result to 7, it will result to 8, it will be ```5 * 5 / 5 + 3;``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190070/discussion-between-mark-and-ctrlaltdel).

Comment: I have only followed your question which is ```int x = 4;``` but you changed it to ```int x = 3;```

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.  "since Java executes equations from left to right" is strange. How about rules of maths and priority? In your case, the expression 2 + 2 * 2 will be 8 because Java executes from left to right

Comment: @Mark - I think that this is a more detailed and better operator precedence chart than the oracle chart given by the OP - https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 3):

```
long y = 4 * 4 - 4;
```

x will be incremented after this assignment

Everytime x is "called" with x++ it gets incremented after
E.g.

```
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(x++ + x++ * x++ + x++);
    // 1 + 2 * 3 + 4
```

Answer (score 2):

x evaluates to 4, and x++ evaluates to 4 as well, and then gets incremented to 5.
So it's essentially 4 * 4 - 4 , which gives 12 as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is resolved separately, so `x == 4`. Incrementation occurs afterwards, so it's actually `4 * 4 - 4 == 12` and after this operation `x == 5`.

Answer (score 1):

The left side of a subtraction is always computed before the right side because subtraction is left associative i.e. 5 - 2 - 1 is (5 - 2) - 1, not 5 - (2 - 1).

This is why the multiplication happens before the increment. Associativity determines what happens first here, not precedence.