# What the logic behind arr1[i++] = arr2[j++]?

Tags: java, algorithm

I understand that if I have the following assignment

`arr[i++] = 1` 
is equivalent to

```
arr[i] = 1; 
i++;
```

But does

`arr1[i++] = arr2[j++]`

is equivalent to

```
arr1[i] = arr2[j];
i++;
j++;
```

What about

```
int i = 0;
while(i++ < 5){ 
    // do something...
}
```

Does the machine execute the `//do something` first then increase 1 and then evaluate whether i is currently < 5?

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You could just test it and see by yourself. But anyway, your interrogation is a clear sign that such code is hard to understand, and should thus be avoided at all cost. Putting as many instructions as possible in a single line of code only makes the code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: `i++` increments immediately, and returns the previous value.

Comment: `Can someone please help me to understand [Java basics]?` [sunsoft/oracle/whoever tried](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `arr[i++] = 1` is equivalent to

```
int i1 = i;
i = i + 1;
arr[i1] = 1;
```

The difference becomes relevant in an expression like

```
arr[i++] = i;
```

where `i` has been incremented by the time its value is written to the array. I hope this is enough information to resolve your question.

Comment: The best place to remember is this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7 It gives you one simple rule of thumb: expression are _always_, with no exceptions, evaluated from left to right.