# Why does short-circuit evaluation work when operator precedence says it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, java, operator-precedence, short-circuiting

In [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), the equals operator (`==` or `===`) has a higher precedence than the OR operator (`||`). Yet both languages ([JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)) support short-circuiting in `if` statements:

When we have `if(true || anything())`, `anything()` isn't evaluated.

You can also have the following expression: `true || foo == getValue())` - for example in an output statement such as `console.log(...);`, or in an assignment.

Now, according to operator precedence, short-circuiting shouldn't happen, as `===` = `==` > `||` in terms of precedence. (In other words, the comparison should happen first, for which `getValue()` ought to be called, as the equality check has a higher precedence that the OR comparison.) But it does. `getValue()` isn't called (as can easily be checked by putting an output statement into its body).

Why (does short circuiting work when the operator precedence says it shouldn't)?
 Or am I confusing matters?

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800590)

Comment: You have a contradiction in your question. You said "...the comparison should happen first... getValue() ought to be called... But it does." So part of your question implies that `getValue()` is not called, but this statement says that is _is_ called. Which is it?

Comment: @Chloe: His *"but it does"* is referring to *"short circuiting shouldn't happen"*, which balances with his concern that *"`getValue()` ought to be called..."* and his observation that *"`getValue()` isn't called"*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Or am I confusing matters?

You are. I think it's much simpler to think about precedence as *grouping* than ordering. It affects the order of evaluation, but only *because* it changes the grouping.

I don't know about Javascript for sure, but in Java operands are always evaluated in left-to-right order. The fact that `==` has higher precedence than `||` just means that

```
true || foo == getValue()
```

is evaluated as

```
true || (foo == getValue())
```

rather than

```
(true || foo) == getValue()
```

If you just think about precedence in that way, and then consider that evaluation is always left-to-right (so the left operand of `||` is always evaluated before the right operand, for example) then everything's simple - and `getValue()` is never evaluated due to short-circuiting.

To remove short-circuiting from the equation, consider this example instead:

```
A + B * C
```

... where `A`, `B` and `C` could just be variables, or they could be other expressions such as method calls. In Java, this is guaranteed to be evaluated as:

- Evaluate `A` (and remember it for later)
- Evaluate `B`
- Evaluate `C`
- Multiply the results of evaluating `B` and `C`
- Add the result of evaluating `A` with the result of the multiplication

Note how even though `*` has higher precedence than `+`, `A` is still evaluated before either `B` or `C`. If you *want* to think of precedence in terms of ordering, note how the multiplication still happens before the addition - but it still fulfills the left-to-right evaluation order too.

Comment: While I totally get short-circuiting, I still fail to see why it works with the rules. Essentially, we have `operand1 operatorA operand2 operatorB operand3` with `operatorA`'s preceence being lower that `operatorB`'s, so operator precedence should cause `o2 oB o3` to be evaluated first. Instead (due to short circuiting) the interpreter sees `operatorA` is an OR and thus only evaluates `operand1`. That evaluates to `true`, so nothing else gets evaluated. Despite operator precedence stating it should be the other way round; the `o2 oB o3` should run first.

Comment: @Christian: "so operator precedence should cause o2 oB o3 to be evaluated first" - no, it really doesn't. Operator precedence means it's grouped such that the operands of operatorA are "operand1" and "the result of evaluating operatorB". But operand1 is still evaluated first. That what I mean about it being more about grouping.

Comment: In fact, the left-to-right rule only applies to operands of the same order: `1 + 2 + 3 => 3 + 3 => 6` whereas `1 + 2 * 3 => 1 + 6 => 7`, not `3 * 3 => 9`, right? If so, we're back at square one, because the `||` has a lower order than the `==`, yet evaluates first (i.e. we get 9, instead of 6)...

Comment: @Christian: No, that's associativity you're thinking of. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7: "The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated." So the left-hand operand of `||` is evaluated before the right-hand operand is evaluated.

Comment: @Christian: You might find this blog post I wrote about the topic a while ago useful: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/04/21/precedence-ordering-or-grouping/

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. In the meantime, for all other non-native speakers out there, be aware that a bitwise operator like `|` is not the same as (but an example of) a binary operator (that works on two operands, as opposed to the ternary one, `? :` that works with three), if I'm not mistaken. That nearly got me. Also just found out that Java calls braces "separators", not "operators" in the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12

Comment: I had to read Eric Lippert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801431/2018047) to a question [referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506098/why-does-short-circuit-evaluation-work-when-operator-precedence-says-it-shouldn#comment79966639_46506098) by @pshermo, and your blog post, but now your answer makes sense. Thank you. To summarise what I understand: the operators determine what operands (or results) get grouped together, but the "subexpressions are evaluated left to right", and because of short-circuiting, it stops after evaluating the left-most to `true` (followed by `||`).

Comment: This explanation was helpful, by the way I think it applies in the same way to JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to the language specification, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.

So if you have `a || b==c`, it is not interpreted as `(a || b) == c`, because `||` has lower precedence, as you found in the tutorial. Instead, it is interpreted as `a || (b==c)`. Now since `a` is the left side of `||`, it is evaluated first.

Comment: I find `a || (b==c)` not any less confusing, as the brackets have an even higher precedence in both languages, for Java see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator precedence in this case. What you are questioning is like in `f(callback)` statement the `callback` function being evaluated even before `f`. This can not happen.

On the other hand, in JS the `||` is one of the few places where you can watch laziness at show. The `==` operand (think as if it is an infix function like in fully functional languages) takes two arguments and the one on the left gets evaluated first. If it resolves to `true` the second argument doesn't even get evaluated.