# Can someone explain me why "operator precedence" applies to logical operators like "||", "&&" in javaScript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, operator-precedence, short-circuiting, short-circuit-evaluation

Can someone explain me why operator precedence applies to logical operators like `||` and `&&` in JavaScript? What does that mean in an operation like:

**true ||** false && false

the `false && false` is evaluated first because the `&&` operator is having a higher precedence than the `||` operator in JavaScript. according to how I know the `false && false` is not evaluated by the JavaScript engine because before the || operator there is a `true` literal and when something is `true` before the `||` operator the thing after the `||` operator will not be evaluated this is called "short-circuiting of logical operators" in JavaScript another example will be:

**true ||** alert()

the function call never takes place even though the function call is having higher precedence than the `||` operator and another example is

true || **x = 7**

if short-circuiting of logical operators is true in JavaScript then the above code must not give an error because the **x = 7** is not evaluated, since before the `||` operator there is a `true` literal.

Comment: You have two parts, evaluation order, and precedence. The precedence says that for `true || false && false` it is equal to `true || (false && false)`  and not `(true || false) && false`. You can see the precedence as how the tree out of the expression is built and then this tree is evaluated based on the evaluation order.

Comment: so you mean what happens in here is totally an effect of the `"evaluation order"` of operators

Comment: Not the evaluation order of the operators, but the evaluation order of the expression. You have an expression with operator precedence that defines how the operators and operands are grouped. And you have the evaluation order which defines in which order those groupings defined by the operator precedence are evaluated, and if there is an early out in case that the already evaluated part will be sufficient to know the result of the expression.

Comment: so what about an assignment expression like `x = 7` which operand is evaluated first

Comment: but if evaluation of operators is not the same as operator associativity the assignment `x = 7 ` must first evaluate `x` and later then it must evaluate `7` a good example is x = 5; x += x = 10; first the variable `x` which is before the `+=` is evaluated before the `x = 10` operation is executed

Comment: @t.niese are you sure though `x = x + (x = 10)` is equal to  `x += x = 10` the first operation which is `x = x + (x = 10)` is what happens behind the scenes. because if the order of evaluation of operands is done in the order its written then the same rule should apply to assignment operators of javaScript the first operand should get evaluated first before the second operand another example is `x = 0; y = []; y[x] = x = 1;`

Comment: I will rewrite the comments as answer.

Comment: where yu will rewrite the comments

Comment: Here, but I need some time. Due to the fact that, editing and combining comments is not possible, the whole thing is getting messy and misleading.

Comment: take time friend its all right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator precedence just determines grouping, not actual evaluation order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46506130

- `true || false && false` becomes `true || (false && false)` but is still evaluated from left to right.
- `true || alert()` is evaluated as `true || (alert())` and NOT `(true || alert)()`
- `true || x = 7` is evaluated as `(true || x) = 7` and causes an error, NOT `true || (x = 7)`

Comment: but if the right operation of the `||` operator is having higher precedence why that operation is not evaluated first