# How to implement a simple stack machine?

Tags: parsing, stack, expression

I've read a few articles about this, and have understood roughly what is most commonly used. The most simple and common method seems to be reverse Polish notation, which is as follows. To evaluate an expression, the first two operands are pushed onto the stack, an instruction is read, like an operation such as addition, that operator operates on the two topmost elements of the stack, the two topmost elements are popped off and the result is pushed onto the stack. However this only seems to work with the examples I've seen, but not in other cases. Here are some examples:

The expression:

```
(11 * 22 + 33 * 44) / 121
```

is noted as the following instructions:

```
push 11
push 22
mult
push 33
push 44
mult
add
push 121
div
```

I understand this. Likewise another example in another article is given:

The expression:

```
(12 + 45) * 98
```

has instructions:

```
push 98
push 12  
push 45  
+    
*
```

I understand this too. But suppose in the first example we wanted to reverse the division like the following:

```
 Instead of:
    (11 * 22 + 33 * 44) / 121

    have:
    121 / (11 * 22 + 33 * 44)
```

Now instead of pushing 121 right at the end, it seems that it needs to be pushed right at the start and look something like this:

```
push 121
push 11
push 22
mult
push 33
push 44
mult
add
div
```

As you can see 121 is the first thing pushed rather than the second last in the original example. However because the other parts is in brackets it should be evaluated first, how do you get around this?

I'm also having the same problem with the other examples I've found. How do you order the values and operations correctly? Do you need to look ahead? Or is there a simple way to just walk across the expression and create the instructions? From what I've read this seems to be most simple way of evaluating expressions, and they seem to imply that writing the instructions is really easy as if you can just run across the expression and create the proper reverse polish notation for it. I'm having trouble understanding how to order the values and instructions in the right way.

Comment: As you parse the expression, you build a parse tree (or abstract syntax tree). The structure of the tree is determined by the expression syntax, operator precedence, and so on. From that tree you can readily produce the RPN output by traversing it. This is not meant as a complete answer but should give you some hints for further googling. Good luck!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you so much. These articles, not even the Wikipedia article on stack machine I don't think mentioned abstract syntax trees in doing this. Though I have read a bit about it before. I see now, so first you need an abstract syntax tree. Thank you. Edit: I'm wrong, I clearly read through the Wikipedia part that mentioned the syntax tree.

Comment: "However because the other parts is in brackets it should be evaluated first, how do you get around this?" Is this a self-imposed restriction? I know of know language that requires this.

Comment: @JETM I thought it was brackets first. C++, C, Java? No? I'm probably wrong.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's (he works on compilers for MS) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801431/2201041). I think there's still a valid question here though. I'll compose an answer as my code compiles....

Answer (score 2):

As we discussed in the comments, order of evaluation has nothing to do with operator precedence. For example, in Java subexpressions are evaluated left-to right. In C, order of evaluation is unspecified. Rather, it has a concept of *sequence points*, which basically says "Whatever you need to get done, just make sure it happens before this semicolon."

So your reverse-polish notation can just be constructed left to right without needing to reorder for parentheses. If you're not sure how to construct the RPN at all, pick up a book on parsing or compilers. The Dragon book opens with a detailed example of translating an expression to RPN.

Now, there is one instance where evaluation order does matter. In most languages, `&&` and `||` short-circuit, so we need to avoid evaluating the RHS in some cases. This can be accomplished with a jump instruction.

For example if we have `1 > 2 && 2 < 3`, we might emit the following instructions:

```
push 1
push 2
>
jmp_f lbl0  ; jump if false to label lbl0
push 2
push 3
<
&&
label lbl0
```

(Of course, your VM may not have all these instructions, but this is just an example of how to conditionally evaluate expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. Sorry, I don't understand, in 121 / (11 * 22 + 33 * 44)  the brackets need to be evaluated first. After reading that link I understand we're not guaranteed in C whether the first or second multiplication happens first, but the bit in brackets definitely has to be evaluated first before it's divided into 121, right? This is what I was talking about. When you said you know of no language that requires this, you're not saying that the the brackets DON'T have to be evaluated first? Or is it that I should not be using "evaluated" but instead "calculated"?

Comment: @Zebrafish If you go through the instructions you listed for `121 / (11 * 22 + 33 * 44)`, the operations will happen in the right order, and you will get the correct number.

Comment: So if you have something like `foo() + (bar())`, a C compiler would be allowed to evaluate `foo()` first or evaluate `bar()` first, as long as it has both of the results before it tries to add them together.