# Why is there a NullPointerException in this function call?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class Bar {

 private Foo m_foo;

 private int getNumbers(){
   m_foo=new Foo();
   return 5;
 }


 public void test1(){
   m_foo.print(getNumbers());
 }
}

public class Foo {

 public void print(int x){
   System.out.println(x);
 }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]){
  new Bar().test1();
 }
}
```

The NullPointerException occurs in `test1()`call, but I can't understand the reason behind. Isn't the `m_foo` supposed to be instantiated in the `getNumbers()` which should get evaluated first?

Comment: Have you looked at the byte-code?

Comment: You may find [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java) question helpful. In short, Java generally evaluates statements left-to-right, and so `m_foo` is resolved before the call to `getNumbers()`

Comment: Create the m_foo in the no argument CTor. You started using it way too early :-)

Comment: @Geek That is not really relevant to this question. The OP is asking about a niche case of the order of evaluation of expressions within a statement. You're nitpicking the semantics of the hypothetical code they are using to give an example of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointer occurs at`

```
m_foo.print(getNumbers());
```

because m_foo is initialized in getNumbers method, and it is never got called before calling test1.

> Java executes statement in a sequence from left to right. So first
>   it will check for m_foo object. Ideal way to do this in a constructor
>   of Bar.

```
public Bar(){
    m_foo=new Foo();
 }
```

Comment: This is more or less a restatement of what the OP already stated in their question. As mentioned, the OP expects `m_foo` to be initialized by `getNumbers` within `test1` prior to the call to `m_foo.print`. Their question is why this isn't the case, not why a NPE occurs at all.

Comment: @Brian yes, but my purpose was just to explain in a different way so that it can be understood,