# Is it possible using variables of ArgumentMatchers?

Tags: mockito, argument-matcher, argument-matching

Let's say I have an interface looks like this.

```java
interface Some {

    /**
     * Does some on specified array with specified index and returns the array.
     *
     * @param array the array.
     * @param index the index.
     * @returns given {@code array}.
     */
    byte[] some(byte[] array, int index);
}
```

Here comes a simple stubbing make the `some` method just return given array.

```java
    Some some = spy(Some.class);
    when(some.some(any(), anyInt())
            .thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments(0)};
```

Is it possible or does it make any sense modifying above code like this?

```java
    Some some = spy(Some.class);
    byte[] array = any();        // @@?
    int index = anyInt();        // @@?
    when(some.some(array, index) // @@?
            .thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments(0)};
```

Does it have same or equivalent effects?

Answer (score 1):

In the code posted, the test passes and the effect is equivalent. This is not true in the general case, and you can easily break the code.

For example this works:

```java
Some some = mock(Some.class);
byte[] any = any();
int index = anyInt();

when(some.some(any, index)).thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0]);
var res = some.some(new byte[]{1, 2}, 4);
```

While this with reordered variables does not work:

```java
Some some = mock(Some.class);
int index = anyInt();
byte[] any = any();

when(some.some(any, index)).thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0]);
var res = some.some(new byte[]{1, 2}, 4);
```

Please refer to [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work):

> ### Implementation details
>
> Matchers are stored (as Hamcrest-style object matchers) in a stack contained in a class called [ArgumentMatcherStorage](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorage.java). MockitoCore and Matchers each own a [ThreadSafeMockingProgress](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ThreadSafeMockingProgress.java) instance, which *statically* contains a ThreadLocal holding MockingProgress instances. It's this [MockingProgressImpl](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/MockingProgressImpl.java) that holds a concrete [ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/1.x/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl.java). Consequently, mock and matcher state is static but thread-scoped consistently between the Mockito and Matchers classes.
>
> Most matcher calls only add to this stack, with an exception for matchers like [`and`, `or`, and `not`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html). This perfectly corresponds to (and relies on) the [evaluation order of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800590/1426891), which evaluates arguments left-to-right before invoking a method:
>
> ```java
> when(foo.quux(anyInt(), and(gt(10), lt(20)))).thenReturn(true);
> [6]      [5]  [1]       [4] [2]     [3]
> ```
>
> This will:
>
> 1. Add `anyInt()` to the stack.
> 2. Add `gt(10)` to the stack.
> 3. Add `lt(20)` to the stack.
> 4. Remove `gt(10)` and `lt(20)` and add `and(gt(10), lt(20))`.
> 5. Call `foo.quux(0, 0)`, which (unless otherwise stubbed) returns the default value `false`. Internally Mockito marks `quux(int, int)` as the most recent call.
> 6. Call `when(false)`, which discards its argument and prepares to stub method `quux(int, int)` identified in 5. The only two valid states are with stack length 0 (equality) or 2 (matchers), and there are two matchers on the stack (steps 1 and 4), so Mockito stubs the method with an `any()` matcher for its first argument and `and(gt(10), lt(20))` for its second argument and clears the stack.
>
> This demonstrates a few rules:
>
> - Mockito can't tell the difference between `quux(anyInt(), 0)` and `quux(0, anyInt())`. They both look like a call to `quux(0, 0)` with one int matcher on the stack. Consequently, if you use one matcher, you have to match all arguments.
> - Call order isn't just important, it's *what makes this all work*. Extracting matchers to variables generally doesn't work, because it usually changes the call order. Extracting matchers to methods, however, works great.
>
> ```java
>    int between10And20 = and(gt(10), lt(20));
>    /* BAD */ when(foo.quux(anyInt(), between10And20)).thenReturn(true);
>    // Mockito sees the stack as the opposite: and(gt(10), lt(20)), anyInt().
>
>    public static int anyIntBetween10And20() { return and(gt(10), lt(20)); }
>    /* OK */  when(foo.quux(anyInt(), anyIntBetween10And20())).thenReturn(true);
>    // The helper method calls the matcher methods in the right order.
> ```