# How did it I get this answer?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I have following java code:

```
public class myClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        int x = 20;
        int y = 10;

        double z = x++ - y * 7 / --y + x * 10;
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

I got 223.0 output. But I would like to know the step by step process. Someone please explain it according to operator precedence.

Comment: For educational purposes, try writing out your arithmetic expression using nested parentheses, according to the order of operations rules in Java.

Comment: Terrible title. Edit to describe your particular technical issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator precedence in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112221/operator-precedence-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I decided to write up an answer because there's a *gotcha* in there that is unrelated to operator precedence (see step 3).

**Step 0:** The input expression—

```
   x++ - y * 7 / --y + x * 10;
```

**Step 1:** In terms of operator precedence, increment/decrement have a higher precedence than multiplication/division, and multiplication/division have a higher precedence than addition/subtraction, so add some parentheses to clarify that—

```
   (x++) - (y * 7 / (--y)) + (x * 10);
```

**Step 2:** The next thing to do is to replace the variables with values, taking into account how the pre/post-increment/decrement operators work—

```
   20 - (10 * 7 / 9) + (21 * 10)
//  ^             ^      ^
//  |           Pre-1    |
//  |                    |
//  + -----------------Post+1
```

**Step 3:** The only thing not related to operator precedence: performing an operation on integer operands yields an integer result, even if the result of the expression is assigned to a floating point type. Therefore, `10 * 7 / 9` yields `7`—

```
   20 - (7) + (210)
```

**Step 4:** Expressions are evaluated from left to right—

```
   20 - 7 + 210
   13 + 210
   223
```

**Step 5:** The integer result is assigned to a `double`—

```
   223.0
```