# Ternary Operator and unexpected NullPointerException

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I am getting `NullPointerException` from the below line sometimes.

```
System.out.println("Date::"+ row != null ? row.getLegMaturityDate() : "null");
```

After adding brackets, it is fine.

```
System.out.println("Date::"+ (row != null ? row.getLegMaturityDate() : "null"));
```

Please clarify me the behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why I try to limit nesting statements/expressions as much as possible. If you would split the statement into two, you wouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`"Date::" + row` is never null, although `row` sometimes is.

That is, `"Date::"+ row != null` is equivalent to `("Date::"+ row) != null` which is always true.

Comment: To add to this, you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137690/java-operator-precedence-guidelines

Comment: Thanks Christoffer. got it. @Mike, thanks for the link, informative.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of operator precedence. [Christoffer Hammarström](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168130/ternary-operator/8168152#8168152) has the executive summary. See this page http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php for more detail.