# When am comparing objects through == operator java sop command not printed appended text why?

Tags: java, equals-operator

My code below

```
public class EqualsComMetod_Operator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1=new String("Raja");
    String s2=new String("Raja");
    System.out.println("s1==s2::"+s1==s2);
    // Here the text s1==s2:: not printed on my console why??
  }
}
```

Output:

> false

Am comparing the objects as reference/address and try to print like this:

> s1==s2::false

but directly showing false. Why?

Comment: try `System.out.println("s1==s2::"+(s1==s2));` after enclosing it inside the parenthesis.

Comment: "s1==s2::"+s1==s2 will be interpreted as "s1==s2::"+s1 == s2 which is not true. Thats why you got false. Try this "s1==s2::"+(s1==s2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @SparkOn It's a different problem. OP is not understanding order of operations in this case. As he pointed out, he _knows_ the output of operation `==` is `false`.

Comment: @SparkOn, no, that is not a dup. This is about `+` binding more tightly than `==`.

Comment: @Unihedron i don't find any different context in here

Comment: @SparkOn "Output: `false` Expected output: `s1==s2::false`"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java operator precedence guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137690/java-operator-precedence-guidelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `+` is evaluated before the `==`.

So if you examine the expression `"s1==s2::"+s1==s2`:

First `"s1==s2::"+s1` is evaluated. It results in `"s1==s2::Raja"`.
Then, `"s1==s2::Raja"==s2` is evaluated, and obviously results in `false`.

You can control the precedence using brackets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = new String("Raja");
    String s2 = new String("Raja");
    System.out.println("s1==s2::" + (s1 == s2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Statement should be

```
System.out.println("s1==s2::" + (s1 == s2));
```

Comment: Answer may be posted while someone might be typing doesn't means the answer is copied. There could be only one way of doing things in right way and same answer can be posted by others.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267090/why-are-users-answering-questions-as-quickly-as-possible/267105#267105

Answer (score -3):

When you create two strings using `new`, they are different objects.  The equality operator will always return false even if the strings contain the same content.  This differs from literal strings, which the compiler will optimize to refer to the same object.

```
String s1 = new String("Raja");
String s2 = new String("Raja");
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false

String s3 = "Raja";
String s4 = "Raja";
System.out.println(s3 == s4); // true
```

Comment: OP wants an output of `s1==s2::false`. Your answer does not address it at all.