# Unable to print hashcode and object equals together in Java

Tags: java

Following code block when executed doesn't print the hashCodes and Boolean together. However when i do Boolean.toString(a==c) instead of a==c, it gets printed. Any reasons why this behavior

```
    String a = "Hello";
    String b = new String("Hello");
    String c =b;
    System.out.println(a.hashCode()+" "+b.hashCode()+" "+c.hashCode() + " " + a==c);
```

Comment: That's because the precedence of == is lower than that of +. Try parentheses around a==c.

Comment: Or, in short, you print `(a.hashCode()+" "+b.hashCode()+" "+c.hashCode() + " " + a) == c`

Comment: @ProfessorVector but then the hashCodes should be printed. Even they don't get printed

Comment: 1. Include the orginal error message 2. Include what you expect 3. Include what happens instead 4. do your research before dumping questions onto SO, this is trivial if you have read +any* basic Java tutorial.

Comment: @user3887166 Why should they? `a + b + c + d == e` is still evaluated as `(a + b + c + d) == e`, no matter how many expressions you add.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for the info, i missed that badly.

Comment: [Java operator precedence guidelines.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137690/java-operator-precedence-guidelines) There doesn't seem to be a good reference post on operator precedence yet.

Comment: @user3887166 You didn't. Turing85 said the same 5 minutes before me.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to compare two strings use equals() method .
The equals() function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. Note that string constants are usually "interned" such that two constants with the same value can actually be compared with ==, but it's better not to rely on that.

```
if (strobj.equals(strobj2)) {
    ...
}
```

So if you want to print hashcodes along with the boolean result of comaparison of two strings ,do this

```
 System.out.println(a.hashCode()+" "+b.hashCode()+" "+c.hashCode() + " " + a.equals(c));
```

Comment: This is not the actual problem at hand (no, I did not downvote).

Comment: i just want to differ between the == and equals() method(which is used for strings comparison),also what u r saying is also correct

Comment: Yeah, but you are not answering the question, though you have posted it as an answer. And you should use `equals(...)` for all objects in Java, not only for `String`s.

Comment: @Turing85 No. You should understand when to check for *identity* (`==`) and when to check for *equality* (`equals`), both have their use cases and blindly using one instead of the other isn't the solution, either.

Comment: @Polygnome of course, there are always exceptions =) but normally you want to check for equality. OP wanted specifically to check for identity, which is why this "answer" is no answer.