# How a given if condition is giving true in java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am unable to understand why following if blocks execute. How the if conditions will be evaluated?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (true || (false ||  true) && false)
        {
            System.out.println("How does this condition becomes true.");
        }

        if (false && (false ||  true) || true)
        {
            System.out.println("Same with this condition, why is it true.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137690/java-operator-precedence-guidelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you must already know `false || true` is `true`.

Apart from that, you need to know the other two things:

- [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting).

> The && and || operators "short-circuit", meaning they don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary.

- [Operators and the annoying precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

> When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first. All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated **from left to right**; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

From the precedence table, we know `&&` is higher than `||`.

So in your question, let's do the basic reasoning.

> if (true || (false ||  true) && false)

`true || no_matter_what_is_in_right_side` will be `true`, so we got a `true`.

> if (false && (false ||  true) || true)

This one is trickier than the previous, this time we have to consider the **annoying** precedence. We do the reasoning as:

`false && no_matter_what_is_in_right_side` will be `false` and all we have left is:

```
false || true
```

Again we have `true` in the end.

But if you already noticed the trick: we start from the **rightmost** `true` then we can do the reasoning as the previous one directly get the `true`.

As Michael mentioned, we'd better use parenthesis to express the exact order instead of relying on the **precedence**, which is actually hard to remember ##.

Answer (score 15):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). So adding in parens to emphasize how those are being evaluated:

```
    if (true || ((false ||  true) && false))
// -------------^-------------------------^
```

and

```
    if ((false && (false ||  true)) || true)
// -----^-------------------------^
```

As you can see, you end up with `x || y` where `x` is `true` in the first example, and `y` is true in the second example. Naturally both `true || false` and `false || true` are `true`.

You can see it in action by using a method that outputs what it's doing ([live copy](https://ideone.com/cnSBNy)) (remember that both `||` and `&&` *short-circuit*, meaning they don't evaluate operands that cannot change the result):

```
public class Test
{
    private static boolean b(String label, boolean value) {
        System.out.println(label + ": " + value);
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (b("1", true) || (b("2", false) || b("3", true)) && b("4", false))
        {
            System.out.println("How does this condition becomes true.");
        }

        if (b("5", false) && (b("6", false) || b("7", true)) || b("8", true))
        {
            System.out.println("Same with this condition, why is it true.");
        }
    }
}
```

When run, that outputs:

```
1: true
How does this condition becomes true.
5: false
8: true
Same with this condition, why is it true.
```

Comment: Worth noting: even if you *know* the rules of precedence (and a big number of Java devs don't), it's almost always easier to quickly figure out the logic if you include the parentheses. It also conveys to a reader what your exact intention was -- the number of times I've had to try to infer whether a colleague actually understood the precedence rules when they wrote an expression is not even funny.

Comment: @Michael You are correct about the use of parentheses in conditions, I was looking into some legacy code when I found this. As I did't know operator precedence rule so I couldn't figure out how it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Well we will take a look at the first line:

```
if (true || (false ||  true) && false)
```

Based on priority, everything between `()` will be evaluated first. So, that will be `false ||  true`, we can write `||` as `OR`, that means we get `true OR false`, in that case it will be `true`, since one of the two values is `true`.

Okay let's move on, it becomes like this:

```
if (true || true && false)
```

Now we come to your confused part. We don't read from left to right in this case. We need to take a look at `&&` first instead of `||`. So we need to check the `true && false` evaluation, which will become `false`:

Then we are left with the following statement:

```
if (true || false)
```

Which will become `true` of course. The same happens for the second one.

See mor here: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: Sorry to say this: we do not do `math` here since there is **short circuiting** in logical operation

Answer (score 0):

Using `||` the condition is true if at least one operand is true. E.g. `false || true` results in `true`.

So your first condition is true because of the *first true* `(true || ...`.

```
if (true || (false ||  true) && false)
......|...............................
```

The second condition is true because of the *last true* `... || true)`

```
if (false && (false ||  true) || true)
...................................|..
```

Take a look at the [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_(OR)).

```
OR
  P       Q     P||Q
--------------------
  T       F      T
  F       T      T
  T       T      T
  F       F      F
```