# after adding grades to each subject how can I divide it to by 4

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```java
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       
    double grades;
    grades= Double.parseDouble(comprogGrds .getText())+Double.parseDouble (dsGrds .getText())+ Double.parseDouble (cwGrds.getText())+ Double.parseDouble(multGrds.getText())/4;
        
    if(grades>=90){
        average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }else if(grades>=78 && grades<=79){
      average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }else if(grades>=74 && grades <=75){
       average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }
                
}
```

Comment: Please, describe what exactly you have problems with, what result you get and how this differs from your expected result. For more information, read [ask]. So please [edit] your question to add more text describing your problem.

Comment: Looks like you might have a [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) problem.

Comment: This question would be better if phrased "Why are my numbers not dividing as I expected?" and it can be answered by learning about Java operators and order of operations. Nonetheless I have supplied an answer.

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2137690/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You've just missed a set of parentheses. You're currently only dividing the final number by 4.
Try instead the following.

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       
    double grades;
    grades= (Double.parseDouble(comprogGrds .getText())+Double.parseDouble (dsGrds .getText())+ Double.parseDouble (cwGrds.getText())+ Double.parseDouble(multGrds.getText()))/4;
        
    if(grades>=90){
        average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }else if(grades>=78 && grades<=79){
      average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }else if(grades>=74 && grades <=75){
       average.setText(Double.toString(grades));
    }
                
}
```

As an explanation, if you have `double result = 3+6+9+2/4;`, you will end up with 3+6+9+(2/4). To fix this, a set of parentheses will suffice. `double result = (3+6+9+2)/4;`

Comment: thank you everyone it is already work. thank you so muchhh Godbless to all.

Comment: @Rose if you're satisfied with an answer, be sure to mark it as accepted (the check mark by the upvote) so this question can be closed.